# use smoothing-spline effectively for predictions

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, spline, smoothing

I have a time series given by two vectors

```
x_1 = np.array([119., 122., 129., 142., 159., 162., 179., 182., 189., 194., 197.,
              199., 202., 204., 209., 214., 217., 219., 222., 224., 229., 234.,
              237., 242., 244., 257., 269., 274., 277., 279., 299., 327., 339.])

 y_1 = np.array([0.70, 0.78, 0.80, 0.84, 0.84, 0.83, 0.15, 0.16, 0.26, 0.42,
               0.52, 0.53, 0.60, 0.64, 0.69, 0.56, 0.58, 0.57, 0.60, 0.77,
               0.77, 0.72, 0.77, 0.78 , 0.75, 0.19, 0.24, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29,
               0.31, 0.28, 0.26])
```

I use smoothing spline to fit a model to the time series:

```
x_basis = cr(x_1, df=freedom_df, constraints='center')

# Fit model to the data
model = LinearRegression().fit(x_basis, y_1)

# Get estimates
y_prediction = model.predict(x_basis)
```

so far so good.

In fact I have so many different time series. Each have different length. so, the `x_basis`
and consequently the `y_prediction` will have different length.
since my goal is to feed them into a machine learning model later, they all, as an input, must have the same length. I want them to be every two weeks:

```
X_const = np.arange(start=1, stop=365, step=14, dtype=None)
```

How can I make a good prediction using the trained smoothing spline model for `X_const`?

I do not get a good result When I do the following (the `model.predict` expects a 2D input, so, I cannot just stick `X_const` in there.):

```
x_const_basis = cr(X_const, df=freedom_df, constraints='center')
x_const_basis = pd.DataFrame(x_const_basis)
y_const_pred = model.predict(x_const_basis)
```

I want the black dots to be closer to red/actual values. any suggestion?
[image: the resulting plot]

### If we do a simple linear regression, we get sth like y=1.5x+10; then we can use it to predict y for any desirable x. But with this spline thing, it is a little bit confusing. we have to generate a basis like so: `x_const_basis = cr(X_const, df=freedom_df, constraints='center')`, and even if there are some `x` values in `X_const` that are close original `x` values in `x_1`, the predictions are too different.

The packet imported are:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import sys
from IPython.display import Image
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from math import factorial
import datetime
import time
import scipy
import os, os.path

from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.predstd import wls_prediction_std
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from patsy import cr

from pprint import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
```

Comment: Your final goal is to improve the score of your model, am I right?

Comment: That would be great as well. But the current question is (lets say) the trained model's prediction and `x_1` is good(the red dots are close to actual data, i.e.black dots) . But when I use the trained model to predict values for `X_const` the model's predictions are bad. For example in the 100-150 interval, the black dots (predictions for X_const) are way off, compared to both actual data (y_1, blue dots) and predicted values `y_prediction` (red dots)... so, I guess you can say I want to get better score...

Comment: the trained model is in common when we do the predictions 
`model.predict(x_basis)` and 
`model.predict(x_const_basis)`

so, something must be different in 

x_const_basis = cr(X_const, df=freedom_df, constraints='center') and
x_basis = cr(X, df=freedom_df, constraints='center')